# Troubleshooting Lexmark E210 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer

[From Windows 10 (64 bit), I printed a test page: using this Samsung driver.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/lexmark-e210-driver-for-windows-8/1472ffd8-187c-4e6e-bc5d-a1f5a048be31)

One month later, I am trying to print the test page failed:

[image]

In the device's properties, its status is "This device is working properly".  Print jobs appear in the queue momentarily and then disappear: no printout.

Is there an equivalent to 'ping' the printer?  Diagnostic procedures are appreciated.

Comment: Can you print a demo page like so, just to make sure it still prints: As the printer powers up, all the printer
control panel lights turn on briefly.
1 Press and hold (sheet of paper looking) button when
only the light remains on.
2 Hold down the (sheet of paper looking) button for two
seconds until all lights blink slowly,
then release. The Demo page
prints.

Comment: The ability to print a demo page is built into the printer itself.  You press and hold the button with your finger on the printer.  If you look up the manual to the printer maybe it will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem with Win10. You will also find that none of the other installed drivers (including PDF, XPS, etc) work: none of them create any files or output.

If that is the case, then you have my problem, and you'll find Win10 has added another driver for your printer, and in the process stuffed itself up. To fix it you will first need to tell Win10 not to automatically install network printer drivers. Go to Network & Sharing Centre, click "Change advanced sharing settings" and "Turn off network discovery".

Now delete drivers for your printer and reinstall the correct one. Go to Devices and Printers. First delete all copies of your printer. Then click on any other printer and on the Print Server Properties menu. Click the Drivers tab and remove all instances of your printer from the list. Now reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I fixed it by right clicking on the printer (within devices and printers), printer properties; device options tab, and in printer mode I selected "Samsung ML-1200 Series"; A dialog window opened and I said yes.
Apply and accept.
Now my Lexmark E210 works on my Windows 10 x64